# Ecommerce Tracking Android Product Category

Tags: java, android, google-analytics

My Ecommerce Tracking work correctly I get back the TransactionID, price... on Google Analytics, but I don't see the Product Category on the third Dimension in Conversions. I don't understand why, if it's a typical problème between Android and Google Analytics ?

The values are in variables.

```
Product product = new Product()
        .setId(id)
        .setName(logement)
        .setCategory(typeForm)
        .setBrand("")
        .setVariant("")
        .setPrice(1)
        .setCouponCode("")
        .setQuantity(1);
ProductAction productAction = new ProductAction(ProductAction.ACTION_PURCHASE)
        .setTransactionId(id)
        .setTransactionAffiliation(getResources().getString(R.string.TransactionAffiliation))
        .setTransactionRevenue(1)
        .setTransactionTax(0)
        .setTransactionShipping(0)
        .setTransactionCouponCode("");
HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder builder = new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder()
        .addProduct(product)
        .setProductAction(productAction);

Tracker t = ((App) getActivity().getApplication()).getTracker();
t.setScreenName("Demande");
t.send(builder.build());
```